# How to send parameters to pytest_runtest_call

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following in my conftest.py file

```
 def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config,items):
   with open("C:\Users\xyz\mno\cli_automation\test_configuration\project\test_command.yml", 'r') as stream:
       data_loaded = yaml.load(stream)
       for i in items:
           if i.name == data_loaded.get("test_name"):
               i.add_marker(data_loaded.get("test_type"))
               pytest_runtest_call(i)
```

I am unable to send the loaded yaml configuration details to  my pytest_runtest_call . How can I achieve it ?

Comment: `pytest_runtest_call` is not intended for you to call it directly. Please show an example of your test you want to parametrize.

Comment: The example above where I am calling the 'pytest_runtest_call' has to send the loaded yaml as a parameter when calling the test.